# AngularJS function unable to be called in ng-view

Tags: html, angularjs, slider, ng-view, angularjs-ng-include

Using the following code, I am successfully able to use this angularjs carousel.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('CarouselDemoCtrl', CarouselDemoCtrl);

function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope){
  $scope.myInterval = 3000;
  $scope.noWrapSlides = false;
  $scope.activeSlide = 0;
  $scope.slides = [
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports'
    },
    {
      image: 'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people'
    }
  ];
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    Write your name here <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    Hi {{name}} Those are your photos:  
    <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
        <div>
            <uib-carousel interval="myInterval" active="activeSlide">
                <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" index="$index">
                    <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <h4>Slide {{$index+1}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </uib-slide>
            </uib-carousel>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I divide the content up into a subsequent app.js and then serve it as an html snippet including the carousel using ng-view as follows, it then doesn't work.

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <div ng-include='"./templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"./templates/footer.html"'></div>
    <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>

</body>
```

It seems it's not able to refer to the function? I get the following console error

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'CarouselDemoCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I got the code for the carouseldemo from https://codepen.io/Fabiano/pen/LACzk

Comment: is the controller code inside `app.js`? Or did you leave it in the template?

Comment: This is my app.js

http://pastebin.com/nrHst3vK

I took it out of the html code above and seperated it.

Comment: You can't run plugins in controller that is parent of ng-view. Plugins need to be in directives. Also there is no controller declaration for `CarouselDemoCtrl` it is  global function only

Comment: That demo uses a very old version of angular that did support global functions as controllers

Comment: So following new syntax as a controller, would it then support display through ng-view?

Comment: yes except the plugin will get called before ng-view is loaded

Comment: What would be best practice then to work around that? Creating a directive?

Comment: yes... directive assigned to element will only run when element exists. Also there are lots of angular carousels